# U-Boot - Behaviour of 'go' command

Tags: u-boot

I have written a minimal bare-metal Raspberry Pi-3B program (ARM64- CortexA53) to switch from EL2 (Exception Level 2) to EL1. U-Boot is used as the boot loader. The code is loaded to RAM using the "tftpboot" command. The "go" command is used to start the execution of my program. I am not expecting to return the control back to U-Boot.

When the code switches to EL1 using "ERET" instruction the RAM (the jump location) contains the random data. When I inspect (using JTAG) the RAM (again the jump location) just before the ERET, I can see the valid program there.

The program works as expected without U-Boot. With U-Boot, it executes random data in EL1.

May I know the reason for this behavior? Is there a better alternative to the "go" command?

Thanks a lot,
Little

Comment: "*Is there a better alternative to the "go" command?*" -- There is nothing simpler than the `go` command for transferring execution from U-Boot to another program . It's just a simple procedure call. If you encounter a difference in program behavior, then it's probably a difference in program startup in a fully quiescent system (i.e. a system reset condition) versus a system that has been (partially) initialized by U-Boot. Your program would need to account for that different environment.